# Node js, express delete file at path

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, npm

I have a photo model:

```
var photoSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String},
    path: { type: String},
    vehicle: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'Vehicle' }
  });
```

A photo is deleted with the route:

```
app.delete('/api/photos/:id/delete', photos.delete (app.get('photos')));
```

I can delete the photo from mongo using:

```
exports.deletePhoto = function (dir) {
  function (req, res, next) {
    var id = req.params.id;
    Photos.delete (id, function (err) {
      if (err) return next (err);
      return res.send ({
        status: "200",
        responseType: "string",
        response: "success"
      });
    });
  };
};
```

The photo is saved on disk at

```
app.set('photos', __dirname + '/public/photos');
```

How do I delete the photo from disk in the deletePhoto function?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do as following:

**Router**

```
app.delete('/api/photos/:id', photos.deletePhoto);
```

It follows REST api norms

**Exports**

```
exports.deletePhoto = function (req, res) {
  Photos.remove({_id: req.params.id}, function(err, photo) {
    if(err) { 
       return res.send({status: "200", response: "fail"});
    }
    fs.unlink(photo.path, function() {
      res.send ({
        status: "200",
        responseType: "string",
        response: "success"
      });     
    });
 }); 
};
```

Answer (score 7):

You can delete a file in node with [fs.unlink()](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_unlink_path_callback).